# Resolving On-Premise DNS and Google Cloud Internal DNS Together

Tags: dns, vpn, google-cloud-dns, gke-networking, google-cloud-vpn

I have a question about Cloud DNS or Cloud VPN i don't know which is exactly related with my issue. I have a on-premise network and i have an internal dns for this network which is example.int. I've connected via Cloud VPN this on-premise network with a Cloud VPC in my Google Cloud account.

Both of my resources can access each other correctly but my VM's in Google Cloud vpc does not resolve my dns servers in my on-premise network. For example i can access my on-premise server via it's ip adress from Google Cloud VM but i cannot access it via on-premise-vm-1.example.int domain.

If i use my on-premise dns nameservers in resolve.conf i can access on-premise server but in that case .c..internal dns adresses do not work in my vpc. I want to use both of them.

What should i do you think? I could not find any working documentation for it. I want to resolve my on-premise and google cloud internal dns zones from my gcloud vms. Is there any way to do it without making any change on resolve.conf file in my all servers?

Thanks in advance

I try to change Cloud DNS server policies but when i try to change alternate dns servers in there, i cannot access my .internal dnsses due to metadata server. However, i cannot even access my example.int dnsses.

I also try to adding example.int dns into Cloud VPC as private dns zone. It also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would recommend to use GCP Cloud DNS private forwarding and point your desired on-prem internal DNS name to your on-prem DNS server.

Be aware that the requests will be coming from 35.199.192.0/19, son in your VPN you should include this range to be reached from your GCP project.

A workaround might be to manually create an internal Cloud DNS zone on your GCP project and manually update your DNS registries there too, the downside about this is that any change you want to make you should make it on both sides.